# How do I pass a keyword argument to the forward used by a pre-forward hook?

Tags: python, callback, pytorch, tensor

Given a torch's `nn.Module` with a pre-forward hook, e.g.

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

class NeoEmbeddings(nn.Embedding):
    def __init__(self, num_embeddings:int, embedding_dim:int, padding_idx=-1):
        super().__init__(num_embeddings, embedding_dim, padding_idx)
        self.register_forward_pre_hook(self.neo_genesis)

    @staticmethod
    def neo_genesis(self, input, higgs_bosson=0):
        if higgs_bosson:
            input = input + higgs_bosson
        return input
```

It's possible to let an input tensor go through some manipulation before going to the actual `forward()` function, e.g.

```
>>> x = NeoEmbeddings(10, 5, 1)
>>> x.forward(torch.tensor([0,2,5,8]))
tensor([[-1.6449,  0.5832, -0.0165, -1.3329,  0.6878],
        [-0.3262,  0.5844,  0.6917,  0.1268,  2.1363],
        [ 1.0772,  0.1748, -0.7131,  0.7405,  1.5733],
        [ 0.7651,  0.4619,  0.4388, -0.2752, -0.3018]],
       grad_fn=<EmbeddingBackward>)

>>> print(x._forward_pre_hooks)
OrderedDict([(25, <function NeoEmbeddings.neo_genesis at 0x1208d10d0>)])
```

**How could we pass the arguments (`*args` or `**kwargs`) that the pre-forward hook needs but not accepted by the default `forward()` function?**

Without modification/overriding the `forward()` function, this is not possible:

```
>>> x = NeoEmbeddings(10, 5, 1)
>>> x.forward(torch.tensor([0,2,5,8]), higgs_bosson=2)

----------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-102-8705a40a3cc2> in <module>
      1 x = NeoEmbeddings(10, 5, 1)
----> 2 x.forward(torch.tensor([0,2,5,8]), higgs_bosson=2)

TypeError: forward() got an unexpected keyword argument 'higgs_bosson'
```

Comment: Also on https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-do-i-pass-a-keyword-argument-to-the-forward-used-by-a-pre-forward-hook/54641

Comment: do not call a model's `forward` function explicitly, rather call `x(torch.tensor([0,2,5,8]))` this will send your call through `nn.Module`'s `__call__` method that does some processing before actually calling `x.forward()` function

Comment: a `@staticmethod` does not have `self`, it's *static*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Torchscript incompatible (as of `1.2.0`)

First of all, your example `torch.nn.Module` has some minor mistakes (probably by an accident).

Secondly, you can pass **anything** to forward and `register_forward_pre_hook` will just get the argument that will be passed your your `torch.nn.Module` (be it layer or model or anything) else. You indeed **cannot do it** without modifying `forward` call, but why would you want to avoid that? You could simply forward the arguments to base function as can be seen below:

```
import torch


class NeoEmbeddings(torch.nn.Embedding):
    def __init__(self, num_embeddings: int, embedding_dim: int, padding_idx=-1):
        super().__init__(num_embeddings, embedding_dim, padding_idx)
        self.register_forward_pre_hook(NeoEmbeddings.neo_genesis)

    # First argument should be named something like module, as that's what 
    # you are registering this hook to
    @staticmethod
    def neo_genesis(module, inputs):  # No need for self as first argument
        net_input, higgs_bosson = inputs  # Simply unpack tuple here
        return net_input

    def forward(self, inputs, higgs_bosson):
        # Do whatever you want here with both arguments, you can ignore 
        # higgs_bosson if it's only needed in the hook as done here
        return super().forward(inputs)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    x = NeoEmbeddings(10, 5, 1)
    # You should call () instead of forward so the hooks register appropriately
    print(x(torch.tensor([0, 2, 5, 8]), 1))
```

You can't do it in more succinct way, but the limitation is base's class `forward` method, not the hook itself (and tbh I wouldn't want it to be more succinct as it would become unreadable IMO).

### Torchscript compatible

If you want to use torchscript (tested on `1.2.0`) you could use composition instead of inheritance. All you have to change are merely two lines and your code may look something like this:

```
import torch

# Inherit from Module and register embedding as submodule
class NeoEmbeddings(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_embeddings: int, embedding_dim: int, padding_idx=-1):
        super().__init__()
        # Just use it as a container inside your own class
        self._embedding = torch.nn.Embedding(num_embeddings, embedding_dim, padding_idx)
        self.register_forward_pre_hook(NeoEmbeddings.neo_genesis)

    @staticmethod
    def neo_genesis(module, inputs):
        net_input, higgs_bosson = inputs
        return net_input

    def forward(self, inputs: torch.Tensor, higgs_bosson: torch.Tensor):
        return self._embedding(inputs)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    x = torch.jit.script(NeoEmbeddings(10, 5, 1))
    # All arguments must be tensors in torchscript
    print(x(torch.tensor([0, 2, 5, 8]), torch.tensor([1])))
```

Comment: The idea is to avoid the `super()` because when we want to something like `jit.trace.script` on the model with `super()`, it isn't supported yet =)

Comment: Yeah, sure, you could use composition instead of inheritance in such case, updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Since a [forward pre-hook](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.Module.register_forward_pre_hook) is called with only the tensor by definition, a keyword argument doesn't make much sense here. What would make more sense is to use an instance attribute for example:

```
def neo_genesis(self, input):
    if self.higgs_bosson:
        input = input + self.higgs_bosson
    return input
```

Then you can switch that attribute as appropriate. You could also use a context manager for that:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def HiggsBoson(module):
    module.higgs_boson = 1
    yield
    module.higgs_boson = 0

with HiggsBoson(x):
    x.forward(...)
```

If you have that function already and you really need to change that parameter you can still replace the function's `__defaults__` attribute:

```
x.neo_genesis.__defaults__ = (1,)  # this corresponds to `higgs_boson` parameter
x.forward(...)
x.neo_genesis.__defaults__ = (0,)  # reset to default
```